Example of a strict Conservative halacha ruling
I know Conservative halacha is generally more lenient than Orthodox halacha.
I wanted to know if there's any example of a Conservative halacha ruling which was stricter than the comparative Orthodox ruling, or if not, any example of a Conservative ruling which added restriction, rather than allowance?
A good example would be of a do-not mitzvah that conservative enforces but orthodox does not.
(sorry if I'm mistaken in terminology, I'm not sure which English terms are correct for this halachaic usage)

Welcome to MiYodeya Yechiam and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

I would expect that Conservative Jews believe they are more "stringent" about matters that invoke some ethical aspect (בן אדם לחברו, כבוד הבריות, צער בעלי חיים, etc.). The Orthodox response would likely be that the Conservative are not enacting stringency but are rather transposing alien values onto Judaism.

I remember Rabbi Joel Roth many years ago saying that he did not accept citywide eruvin, and that people should not eat potatoes on Pesach because the custom of kitniot should include them, as they are used to make flour. Don't quote me.

Anytime you deal with a relationship, it's very hard to argue what is "stricter" or more "lenient." I think the Conservative movement required the Lieberman Clause in all of their ketubot, while the Orthodox world still has guys refusing to sign a halachic prenup, passing off their selfishness as piety by claiming "some rabbis don't like it." Of course you could argue that's being more lenient vis-a-vis leaving the traditional documents alone...

The classic example of something like this involves the Reform movement plank that being "raised Jewish" is primordial to being Jewish, to the point that (theoretically) someone born to a non-Jewish mother in a mixed marriage would count for a minyan, while a person born to two Jewish parents who practiced another religion would not. This stringency is probably theoretical, as in they would not be very likely to actually turn away a halachic Jew.

Thanks for all the comments! @יהושעק - I'm not sure I understand your example. Which view is the conservative and which is the orthodox in this case?

@MichoelR the eruvin case is interesting - do you perhaps have a reference?

And @Shalom perhaps more precisely speaking, I can say that an example of a do-not mitzvah that conservative enforces but orthodox does not, would be a good example of "stricter ruling".

@RabbiKaii I meant, it was forty years ago and my memory is pretty vague. Plus I don't know if he was giving rulings or just opinions on what would be good things. Maybe someone could actually research Joel Roth's positions and give a clearer answer.

It's a movement that doesn't follow halacha. An example of "strict conservative halacha" would be something like driving on shabbos but only to go to synagogue

Here is an example that I think I saw on Wikipedia- Man eating with one other man and two women. Orthodox: no mezuman (bc just 2 men). Conservative: Mezuman (4 adults). So in this case the Conservative ruling is the man is obligated to join the mezuman. Orthodox no because there is none. Not really more stringent but rather an obligation that comes into play.

I mean I don’t know if there is anything that is genuinely debatable in Halacha where most conservative rabbis are more stringent than most orthodox rabbis, but in examples whereas conservative rabbis arbitrarily invent concepts foreign to genuine Torah Judaism and Halacha, such as same sex marriage  or prayer services through zoom, the concept where a leniency in one regard leads to a stringency somewhere else applies so for example a child adopted by a same sex couple would have to obey their non halachic parents and a Jew who can’t get to services in person might perform a “mitzvah” by conservative standards by using zoom

The second example is interesting - does that mean that e.g. for a sick exemption from Sukka mitzvah, a conservative Halacha might rule that because they can experience Sukka through Zoom, they're not to be exempt?

@YechiamWeiss I don’t know of any even conservative rabbanim who says one has fulfilled one’s obligation in the sukkah through zoom. My point is broadly that since conservatives invent a lot of halachic fictions to justify leniencies, there will be corresponding stringencies
